# PowerShell: Command stops working once it's within a Start-Job block

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script that will first display a messagebox, and then the script needs to proceed after a certain amount of time if the user doesn't click OK to the messagebox. The messagebox code works fine on its own, and then the code stops working once it's within a Start-Job block.

```
$job = Start-Job {

    $message = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Message body." , "Message title." , 0)

    if ($message -eq "OK" ) {Write-Host "User clicked OK."} 

}

$timeout = Wait-Job $job -Timeout 30

Stop-Job $job 

Receive-Job $job

Remove-Job $job
```

**Error Message:**

> Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

Answer (score 2):

In your scriptblock insert `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` at the beginning.

The job runs in a different PowerShell process so even though you had imported the WinForms assembly in your console, that assembly will not be imported in the new PowerShell session spun up by the job.

Comment: Thanks Keith! That worked great and enabled the messagebox logic to work within the start-job block.

Comment: Now that I'm past the messagebox logic, another problem has been revealed. The start-job timeout should terminate the script after 30 seconds. However the script doesn't continue until the user clicks OK to the messagebox. Any ideas?

Comment: The timeout is on Wait-Job and its function isn't to stop the job, just to continue in the event the job is not complete.  In my tests, that is just what happens.  The script continues to execute after the timeout and then gets hung Stop-Job.  I haven't found a good way to stop a job that has modal UI up like this other than to have the job return the $pid for the process as the first line, then I use Receive-Job to get the PID and then I kill the process with that PID.